# Unterschied zwischen "ungebeten", "ungeladen" und "uneingeladen" in Bezug auf "Gäste"

Tags: difference

> *ungebeten-* nicht aufgefordert, unerwartet und auch nicht erwünscht, nicht gern gesehen
> Bsp. ungebetene Gäste, Besucher
>  *ungeladen-* nicht eingeladen
> Bsp. ungeladene Gäste
>  *uneingeladen-* nicht eingeladen
> Bsp. Sie erschien uneingeladen auf dem Fest
> Quelle: Duden

Ich gehe davon aus, dass die letzten zwei Begriffe die gleiche Bedeutung haben. Gibt es andere Unterschiede zwischen den Wörtern?

Comment: Wenn du die Einträge zuende gelesen hättest, hättest du sicher auch die Unterschiede gefunden...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ungeladen" means "unloaded," while "uneingeladen," means "uninvited."

You can also make a distinction between "uneingeladen" (uninvited) and "ungebeten" (unasked). This "unasked" does *not* mean that a question was unasked, but rather that you were "unasked" to do something.

"Ungeladen" meint "unloaded;" "Uneingeladen," meint "uninvited."

Es gibt auch ein Underschied zwischen "uneingeladen" (uninvited) und "ungebeten" (unasked).

Ein Gast ist uneingeladen.
Eine Anfrage ist unbeten.
Ein Wagen ist ungeladen.